# Elixir Ecto get all records between two unix epochs

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to to what I thought was a pretty basic ecto query to get the records from between two unix timestamps. Something along the lines of:

```
b = Ecto.DateTime.from_unix!(begin_utc_epoch, :second)  |> DateTime.to_naive
e = Ecto.DateTime.from_unix!(end_utc_epoch, :second)  |> DateTime.to_naive
query = from r in MyModel,
where r.inserted_at > ^b and r.inserted_at < ^e
```

I am getting nothing but errors. At the moment it is:

(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in DateTime.to_naive/1

I read somewhere that I should be using NaiveDateTime so have been trying to convert to naive time stamps. Any help would be appreciated. I am sure I am doing something wrong because it seems too complicated.  Obviously, I am very new to Elixir.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `inserted_at` data type is a NaiveDateTime, then you can just work with `DateTime` for the conversion:

```
b = DateTime.from_unix!(begin_utc_epoch)  |> DateTime.to_naive
e = DateTime.from_unix!(end_utc_epoch)  |> DateTime.to_naive

query = 
  from r in MyModel,
  where: r.inserted_at > ^b and r.inserted_at < ^e
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  i tried that and it complained.  I might be using a different version (I am using elixir 1.4.2) or something.  Its the usual, I am in a rush and have to move on.

Comment: also, I am very new to Elixer and Phoenix, so I make a ton of silly mistakes. So its probably on my side

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it in a relatively clean way:

```
b = NaiveDateTime.add(~N[1970-01-01 00:00:00], begin_utc_epoch)
e = NaiveDateTime.add(~N[1970-01-01 00:00:00], end_utc_epoch)
query = from r in MyModel,
    where r.inserted_at > ^b and r.inserted_at < ^e
```

what was messing me up is that I thought the timestamps in the query results where Ecto.DateTimes (did not know what the sigils ~N[blah blah] where. They are NaiveTimeStamps. I was comparing apples to oranges. Doh!